# Execute Java Class and display Result in Console Using Maven Surefire

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to execute class file from my maven test folder. The class file I am referring here is java class not junit test. How do I execute this and display the result in console using surefire plugin?

In my POM I added this, but I think I am missing something here

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.14.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <useFile>false</useFile>
    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
     </goals>
       <phase>test</phase>
</plugin>
```

My java class file that I am trying to execute is com\test\java\RunTest.java

Comment: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/ if you just want to execute main method

Comment: I am trying with surefire if possible

Comment: it's not possible. surefire has a different goal. use the exec plugin